# Как изменить style class uidocument в коде?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код:

```
public class Main_Interface : MonoBehaviour
{
    Button okButton;
    void Start()
    {
        var uiDocument = GetComponent<UIDocument>();
        okButton = uiDocument.rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("Up1");
        okButton.clicked += ClickMessage;

        StyleSheet uss = Resources.Load<StyleSheet>("interface");
    }
}
```

Я получил доступ к списку классов стилей и к объекту, но как изменить класс объекта, например, кнопки на определенный из списка я так и не нашел.
То есть нужно изменить внешний вид применив другой класс, что-то на подобие:hover, только через код

Comment: Поменять что бы что? Он в любом случае не сохранится.

Comment: А почему он не должен сохраниться? Все равно пришлите, как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VisualElement](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.html)

| Public Methods |  |
| --- | --- |
| [AddToClassList](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.AddToClassList.html) | Adds a class to the class list of the element in order to assign styles from **USS**. |
| [RemoveFromClassList](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.RemoveFromClassList.html) | Removes a class from the class list of the element. |
| [GetClasses](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.GetClasses.html) | Retrieve the classes for this element. |
| [ClearClassList](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.ClearClassList.html) | Removes all classes from the class list of this element. |
| . . . |  |

Грузить стиль не нужно, он должен быть в списке стилей твоего `uxml` документа или клонированного темплейта документа (добавляются в общий список корневого) и просто указываешь имя.